# Issue building apk file

Tags: android, gradle

I am working with an Application where I enabled runProguard true in my build.gradle file of my app. When I go for building signed apk I am getting warnings and build process failed.

**Log File:**

```
Warning:com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Ascii: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$StringConverter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.base.Converter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Converter$ConverterComposition: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Converter$FunctionBasedConverter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Converter$ReverseConverter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Defaults: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Enums$StringConverter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Equivalence$EquivalentToPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Equivalence$Wrapper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue$FinalizerLoader: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Function: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.FunctionalEquivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$ForMapWithDefault: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$FunctionComposition: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$FunctionForMapNoDefault: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$IdentityFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$PredicateFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$SupplierFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.base.Joiner$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Joiner$MapJoiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.base.MoreObjects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.MoreObjects$ToStringHelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Objects$ToStringHelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Optional: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.PairwiseEquivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Preconditions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$AndPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$AssignableFromPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$CompositionPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$ContainsPatternPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$InPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$InstanceOfPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$IsEqualToPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$NotPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$ObjectPredicate$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$ObjectPredicate$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$ObjectPredicate$3: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$ObjectPredicate$4: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Predicates$OrPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Present: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    signingConfigs {

    }
    compileSdkVersion 21

    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15

        targetSdkVersion 21

        versionCode 1

        versionName '1.0'

    }
    buildTypes {

        release {

            runProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 

'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    productFlavors {

    }
        packagingOptions {

            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'

            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2-beta+'

    compile (group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-notifications-handler', version: '1.0.1', ext: 'jar')

    compile project(':library')

    compile project(':StyleableDateTimePicker-master')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0+'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'

    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.1.0@aar'

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'

    compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.1'

    compile('ch.acra:acra:4.5.0') {

        exclude group: 'org.json'
    }

    compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: I solved this issue.

Comment: That great :) you can remove your post or public answer to others

Comment: @user3351125 May I know how do you solve it? Could you kindly post your answer so that others can reference it as well :)

Answer (score 6):

I think I finally figured this one out!

gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    /* Required for using guava with proguard */
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

Additions to my proguard configuration:

```
##-------------Begin Settings For Guava ------------------------------------------------------------
#https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-guava.pro
# Configuration for Guava
#
# disagrees with instructions provided by Guava project: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava
#
# works if you add the following line to the Gradle dependencies
#
# provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
-keep class com.google.common.io.Resources {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.common.collect.Lists {
    public static ** reverse(**);
}
-keep class com.google.common.base.Charsets {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class com.google.common.base.Joiner {
    public static Joiner on(String);
    public ** join(...);
}

-keep class com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$ReferenceEntry
-keep class com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$ReferenceEntry

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

##-------------End Settings For Guava --------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Links Which Helped Me

- https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-guava.pro
- https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/issues/53

Answer (score -9):

You can't use proguard anymore, you need use

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Comment: I solved this issue with using runProgurad true, no need to use minifyEnabled true

Comment: ok, i had see in documentation, whe use gradle 1.+, use the minifyEnable, thas solve problems in current android studio version

Comment: disabled proguard is not a solution